How do i enable user to login with new password after reseting it
I am trying to create a password reset system in django. So the issue is that I'm trying to login my user after resetting the password but the system throws an Invalid credentials error.
I used a custom user model that takes in username as the unique identifier.
Here is the login code in views.py
def ilogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f'Welcome {username}!')
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            if myUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid credentials provided.')
            else:
                print('eeeeeee')
                messages.error(request, f'Account with username "{username}" does not exist. Please create an account.')
            return redirect('login')  # Redirect back to login page
    else:
        return render(request, 'user/login.html')

here the code for reseting the password:
def password_reset_confirm(request, token):
    try:
        reset_token = PasswordResetToken.objects.get(token=token)

        if not reset_token.is_valid:
            messages.error(request, 'This reset link is expired or invalid.')
            return redirect('login')
        
        if request.method == 'POST':
            new_password = request.POST.get('new_password')
            confirm_password = request.POST.get('cofirm_password')

            if new_password == confirm_password:
                user = reset_token.user
                print(user)
                user.set_password(new_password)
                user.save()

                reset_token.is_used = True
                reset_token.save()

                messages.success(request, 'Your password has been reset successfully.')
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Password do not match')

        return render(request, 'emails/password_reset_confirm.html')    

    except PasswordResetToken.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid password reset link')
        return redirect('login')

Here is the PasswordResetToken code:
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
# Create your models here.

User = get_user_model()#created a custom user model to use username as unique identifier
class PasswordResetToken(models.Model):
   user       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   token      = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)  
   is_used    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   validity_period = 300 #how long the token is valid(5 mins)

   def __str__(self):
       return f'Password reset token for {self.user.username}'
   
   class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = 'Password Reset Tokens'

   @property
   def is_valid(self):
       return not self.is_used and (timezone.now() - self.created_at).total_seconds() < self.validity_period


**mycustom user model** code:

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager,PermissionsMixin
# Create your models here.

class myUserManager(BaseUserManager):
     def create_user(self,username,email,password=None, **extra_fields):
          if not username:
               raise ValueError('The username field must be included')
          if not email:
               raise ValueError('The email field must be provided')
          
          username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
          email    = self.normalize_email(email)

          extra_fields.pop('email', None)
          user  = self.model( username = username, email=email, **extra_fields )
          user.set_password(password)
          user.save( using = self._db )
          return user
     
     def create_superuser( self,username,email,password=None, **extra_fields ):
          extra_fields.setdefault( 'is_staff', True )
          extra_fields.setdefault( 'is_superuser',True)

          return self.create_user( username, email, password, **extra_fields )

class myUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    username    = models.CharField( max_length = 255, unique=True ) 
    email       = models.EmailField( unique= True )
    is_staff    = models.BooleanField ( default=False ) 
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  

    objects = myUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD  =  'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS =   ['email']

    def __str__(self):
         return self.username
    
    class Meta:
         verbose_name        = 'User'
         verbose_name_plural = 'Users'


I am tryin to create a user password reset system via email in django.I do get the email and everything.It is when I a trying to login with the new password that system fails to work.

The password and username should be saved in a database. Then you update the password if the password_reset_confirm is activated.

Could elaborate more on this. I dont get it.

In the case where a user resets or changes their password while already logged in to the application, it's important to invalidate their existing session. This is because the user's credentials stored in the session (typically username and a temporary token representing their logged-in state) become outdated after the password change.
log out after reset/changing if user is in session

@Shekhrozx they seem to be using the builtin auth mechanism in Django, unless their custom user touches things it shouldn't there's logic in there which causes sessions to get invalidated as long as the password changes. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change

Show us 1) the code for the PasswordResetToken model, 2) the code that stored that token in the database. Potentially your custom user model might also be useful. Also note that Django has builtin views to reset the password, so you don't really need to create those yourselves. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView

@AbdulAzizBarkat I have added the custom user model and also the model to handle password reset token. Any ideas?
